# Get recurring charges and fees from Yodlee API

Tags: yodlee

How can i get reocurring charges and fees from Yodlee API?

Can i know which API to get the details and field name to fetch the above details from Yodlee.

And also for available credits.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
How can i get reocurring charges and fees from Yodlee API?
```

There is no specific API to return these data points. You will have to look at the transactions and identify these.

```
And also for available credits.
```

This value will be present in the account level or statement level information retrieved from this [Data service](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getItemSummaryForItem1) for a card account.